# Messages dispatching sytem design in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, akka

I am looking for a lightweight and efficient solution for the following use case:

- The gateway module receives resources to deliver for different acceptors.
- The resources queued (by order of arrive) for each acceptor.
- A purge process scans those queues, if resources are available for some acceptor then he bundles them under some tag (unique id) and sends a notification that a new bundle is available.

System characteristics:

- The number of acceptors is dynamic.
- No limitations on number of resources in one bundle.

[image: Message Dispatching System]

The module will be used in Tomcat 7 under Java 7 (not clustered).

I considered the following solutions:

1. **JMS** - dymanic queue configuration for each acceptor, is it possible to consume all available messages in a queue? Threads configuration per queue (not scalable)?
2. **AKKA Actors**. Didn't find a suitable pattern for usage.
3. **Naive pure Java implementaion**, where queues will be scanned by one thread (round robin).

I think that this is the right place to discuss about available solutions for this problem. 
Please share your ideas when considering the following points:

- Suitable third parties frameworks.
- Resources queues scalable scanning.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use various technologies eg:

- **JMS dynamic queues**
- **Extended LMAX disruptor** ( eg. https://github.com/hicolour/disruptor-ext)
  [image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hicolour/disruptor-ext/master/disruptor-multi-ring.jpg]

but from the high **availability** and **scalability** reasons you should use **Akka**

**Akka**

The starting point for your implementation will be Consistent Hashing routing algorithm built into Akka - in simple words this type of routing logic selects consistent route based on a provided key. **Routes** comparing to your problem description are **acceptors**.

Router actor comes in two distinct flavors, which gives you flexible mechanism to deploy new acceptors in your infrastructure.

- Pool - The router creates routees as child actors and removes them from the router if they terminate.
- Group - The routee actors are created externally to the router and the router sends messages to the specified path using actor selection, without watching for termination.

First of all please read Akka routing documentation to get better understanding of routing implementation in the Akka framework:

- http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.7/java/routing.html

You can also check this article about scalable and high available systems design:

- http://prochera.com/blog/2014/07/15/building-a-scalable-and-highly-available-reactive-applications-with-akka-load-balancing-revisited/

**Q1  Is it possible for Actor to know his route (his hash key)?**

Actor may know what key is currently handled, because it may be just part of the message - but you shouldn't build cross-messages logic/state based on this key.

Message:

```
import akka.routing.ConsistentHashingRouter.ConsistentHashable
  class Message(key : String) extends ConsistentHashable with Serializable {
      override def consistentHashKey(): AnyRef = key
  }
```

Actor:

```
  import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorLogging}

  class EchoActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {

    log.info("Actor created {}", self.path.name)

    def receive = {
      case message: Message =>
        log.info("Received message {} in actor {}", message.consistentHashKey(),             self.path.name)
      case _ => log.error("Received unsupported message");
    }
  }
```

**Q2 Can Actor manage a state except his mailbox?**

Actors states can be changed only through the messages sent between them.

If you will initialize actor containing reference to the classic java/spring/.. bean, it will be able to interact with non-actor world/state eg. dao layer, but this type of integration should be limited as possible and treated as anti pattern.

**Q3 Is there a way to use configuration that is collision resistant?**

As an API consumer, you need to define on your own hand `collision resistant` model, but once again Akka gives infrastructure required to do it.

1. In most cases key will be part of the domain eg. auction id , customer id
2. If key needs to be generated on demand you can use an [ClusterSingleton](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/contrib/cluster-singleton.html)
   with [Persistence](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/persistence.html) extension.

`Generator` may be an `Actor` responsible for the generation of the unique ID, other actor may obtain new id using `ask` pattern.

`ClusterSingleton` is initialized using `ClusterSingletonManager` and obtained using `ClusterSingletonProxy`

```
system.actorOf(ClusterSingletonManager.props(
singletonProps = Props(classOf[Generator]),
singletonName = "gnerator",
terminationMessage = End,
role = Some("generator")),
name = "singleton")


system.actorOf(ClusterSingletonProxy.props(
singletonPath = "/user/singleton/generator",
role = Some("generator")),
name = "generatorProxy")
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I read the Akka routing documentation, still some points are missing: Is it possible for Actor to know his route (his hash key)? Can Actor manage a state except his mailbox?

Comment: @MaximKirilov answers above, take a look on typesafe activator and its examples https://typesafe.com/activator

Comment: Hi, another question: I see that there is collisions when using consistent hashing. There is a way to use configuration that is collision resistant. For example is I know that maximum 100 different hashing keys will be generated?

Comment: "collision resistant" is large topic, but in case of unique keys you can use singleton pattern

Answer (score 0):

I think for your problem JMS will the proper solution. You can go with RabbitMQ which has routers which route messages to different queue as per the key and provides built in solution for message flow and message acknowledgement mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Apache Camel for this. Its lightweight and supports alot of [enterprise integration patterns](http://camel.apache.org/enterprise-integration-patterns.html). [Particularly Content Based Router](http://camel.apache.org/content-based-router.html) is a possible solution.